# find text in array and surround it with <span> html tag without changing the case

Tags: php, regex

In PHP I have a array and I would like to surround all instances of $text with  html tag without changing the case.
For example :

```
$text = "aa";
array("aa", "baa", "aab", "bb", "Aa");
```

will become

```
array("<span>aa</span>", "b<span>aa</span>", "<span>aa</span>b", "bb", "<span>Aa</span>");
```

Using `str_ireplace` will change `Aa` to `aa`.

I already tryed :

```
preg_replace('.*(' . $text . ').*', '<span style="background-color: #FFFF00">"$1"</span>', $val);
```

but I get this error `Unknown modifier '*''`

**EDIT :**

What regex expresion can I use to to achieve the result like in the example ?

Comment: What regex expresion can I use to achieve the result like in the example ?

Comment: Put brackets around your regex `/.*(' . $text . ').*/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*In the regex case:*

You just forgot to put brackets around your regex.

```
$text = "aa";
$val = array("aa", "baa", "aab", "bb", "Aa");
$val = preg_replace('/.*(' . $text . ').*/i', '<span style="background-color: #FFFF00">"$1"</span>', $val);
print_r($val);
```

Comment: Yes, but it will not replace `Aa`, only `aa`. Now I am using `preg_replace('/(.*)(' . $text . ')(.*)/', '$1<span style="background-color: #FFFF00">$2</span>$3', $val);`

Comment: Oh, try putting `i` after the last bracket `/.*(' . $text . ').*/i` (**case insensitive**)

Comment: @lonut To replace without being case sensitive change it to `preg_replace('/.*(' . $text . ').*/i', '<span style="background-color: #FFFF00">"$1"</span>', $val);`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I'm too late, but here was a non-regex version I made.

```
$text = "aa";
$input = array("aa", "aab", "baa", "bb", "Aa");

$output = array();
foreach($input as $in) {
    $pos = stripos($in, $text);
    $extract = substr($in, $pos, strlen($text));
    $output[] = substr_replace($in, "<span>$extract</span>", $pos, strlen($text));
}

var_dump($output);

//produces:

array (size=5)
  0 => string '<span>aa</span>' (length=15)
  1 => string '<span>aa</span>b' (length=16)
  2 => string 'b<span>aa</span>' (length=16)
  3 => string '<span>bb</span>' (length=15)
  4 => string '<span>Aa</span>' (length=15)
```